# Are nested fmap calls idiomatic Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
*Main> :t text
text
  :: (Selectable s, StringLike str, Ord str) => s -> Scraper str str
```

I need to perform "second level" `fmap` operation:

```
*Main> let z = fmap (fmap (:[])) text
*Main> :t z
z :: (Selectable s, StringLike a, Ord a) => s -> Scraper a [a]
```

On one hand `z` follows API structure, but otherwise I find such code hard to read. It feels like programming against stack-based machine.

Comment: In a word: yes. This stuff comes up more than you might think. If you’re nesting them 3 or more layers deep, maybe reconsider, but 2 levels is not uncommon at all.

Comment: You can write it `(fmap . fmap) (:[]) text`, or `((.) . fmap) text` to point at that level of fmap being the instance for functions.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can wrap the "nested functors" in a newtype which is itself a functor, use a single `fmap` on the newtype, and unwrap. In your case:

```
import Data.Functor.Compose

let z = getCompose . fmap (:[]) . Compose $ text
```

We are composing the `((->) s)` and `Scraper a` functors.

The problem with this is that it trades `newtype` noise for nested `fmap` noise.

Answer (score 1):

Nested fmaps are very normal in haskell and extremely common, consider:

```
 myList = [Just 13, Just 7, Just 33, Nothing, Just 23]

exampleFunc :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int]
exampleFunc li = map (\el -> fmap (+1) el) li
```

The prelude map function is a child of the fmap type, so this simple function is using nested fmap's.